# Can I rely on the order of an unordered map?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, language-lawyer, multimap

I have an `std::unordered_multimap` and I want to get the last inserted element of a specific key. I observed this behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unordered_multimap<string, string> mmap;

    mmap.emplace("a", "first");
    mmap.emplace("a", "second");
    mmap.emplace("a", "last");
    mmap.emplace("b", "1");
    mmap.emplace("b", "2");
    mmap.emplace("b", "3");

    auto last_a = mmap.equal_range("a").first;
    auto last_b = mmap.equal_range("b").first;

    cout << last_a->second << endl;
    cout << last_b->second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs:

```
last
3
```

This is, at least, on GCC, the behaviour I want. Can I rely on this? Does the standard say simething about the order the `std::unordered_multimap` store things? If not, what would be the best alternative?

Comment: You'll get `first 1` with [libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8f56abb25674bbe).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost.

> `[C++14: 24.2.5/6]:` *[..]* In containers that support equivalent keys, elements with equivalent keys are adjacent to each other in the iteration order of the container. Thus, although **the absolute order of elements in an unordered container is not specified**, its elements are grouped into equivalent-key groups such that all elements of each group have equivalent keys. **Mutating operations on unordered containers shall preserve the relative order of elements within each equivalent-key group unless otherwise specified.**
>
> `[C++14: 24.2.5/9]:` *[..]* **For unordered_multiset and unordered_multimap, rehashing preserves the relative ordering of equivalent elements.**

It's pretty awkward wording but, from what I can tell, the general notion is that the order of elements underneath equivalent keys is unspecified, though it at least pretty much stays the same afterwards.

So:

**You can't rely on insertion order, but you can probably rely on a stable order if you're careful.**

This is in contrast with the ordered associative containers:

> `[C++14: 23.2.4/4]:` **For multiset and multimap, insert, emplace, and erase preserve the relative ordering of equivalent elements.**

Comment: But it's not specified where the new element is inserted. If you have `a, b, c` in the equivalent-key group, and insert `d`, the relative order of `a`, `b`, and `c` won't change, but you can insert `d` in any of the four places.

Comment: @T.C. Which may or may not be ok

Answer (score 1):

`std::unordered_multimap` is neither ordered (obviously) nor *stable*.  So the order you put equivalent elements into the `std::unordered_multimap` are in no way guaranteed to be consistent by the standard.

Comment: The wording suggests a strong degree of stability.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit equivalent elements are only guaranteed to be in a contiguous subrange of the iteration order.

Comment: @P​​​​​​​​​​​​aulEvans I am aware.